# Twython : cursor on statuses/get_user_timeline returns my tweets instead of screen_name passed

Tags: twython

I started using Twython recently and was impressed by the simplicity. Thanks for the developing and maintaining the library.

However, when I tried running a cursor on get_user_timeline() endpoint, I got my timeline instead of the user specified in the 'screen_name' parameter. I ran the following with App auth.

`twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=self.ACCESS_TOKEN)
 tweets = twitter.request("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", "GET", {'screen_name': '<some screen name>'})`

that worked just fine for 20 tweets or 1 page worth of tweets.

I am wondering then why my below stated code did not work? 
`twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=self.ACCESS_TOKEN)
tweets = twitter.cursor(twitter.get_user_timeline, {"screen_name":"narendramodi"})`

Am I using the cursor wrong? If so what would be an ideal way of using the endpoint in question.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Thanks and Regards,
Atul.

Answer (score 0):

This problem of getting the tweets from the authenticated user happened to me before. The reason was that I was giving as argument an non-existent user. Make sure you don't confuse the name with the screen-name.